# Group by does not show all the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a table `tblPersonaldata` and `tblStudentsadmitted`

```
tblPersonalData

UID  Name Gender
------------------------ 
 E1   xyz   M
 E2   pqr   M
 E3   mno   M

tblStudentsadmitted

UID   Status  Stage
----------------------
E1     Y        1
E2     Y        2
E3     Y        1
```

Now I want the data like this:

```
Gender  Stage1   Stage2
 M        2       1
```

But in this case I dont get the data for female gender. I want the data for female gender even if it is null

I have tried this:

```
select 
    case 
        when gender='M' then 'Male' 
        when gender='F' then 'Female' 
    end as Gender,
    sum(case when Stage=1 then 1 else 0) end as Stage1,
    sum(case when Stage=2 then 1 else 0) end as Stage2
from  tblPersonaldata A inner join 
      tblStudentsadmitted B on A.UID=B.UID 
where B.Status='Y'
group by Gender
```

Comment: Are your sample tables all the information you have?
As you dont have any female data there?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN a.Gender = 'M' THEN 'Male' ELSE 'FEMALE' END Gender,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Stage = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Stage1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Stage = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Stage2
FROM    personal a
        LEFT JOIN studentadmitted b
            ON a.UID = b.UID AND b.Status = 'Y'
GROUP   BY a.Gender
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/673c3/2)

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN c.Gender = 'M' THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END Gender,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Stage = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Stage1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Stage = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Stage2
FROM    (SELECT 'F' Gender UNION SELECT 'M' Gender) c
        LEFT JOIN personal a
            ON a.Gender = c.Gender
        LEFT JOIN studentadmitted b
            ON a.UID = b.UID AND b.Status = 'Y'
GROUP   BY c.Gender
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/673c3/10)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ GENDER ║ STAGE1 ║ STAGE2 ║
╠════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ Female ║      0 ║      0 ║
║ Male   ║      2 ║      1 ║
╚════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: @user1274646 would you mind if you post your query? maybe you have missed something,

Comment: @JW yes i got it d query is running but still i don get female row

Comment: there should be,  can you post the query? `:D` see this fiddle, it's working right? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/673c3/10

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you can use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to generate the result:

```
select gender,
  Stage1, 
  Stage2
from
(
  select 
    c.gender,
    'Stage'+cast(stage as varchar(10)) Stage
  from (values ('F'),('M')) c (gender)
  left join tblpersonaldata p
    on c.gender = p.gender
  left join tblStudentsadmitted s
    on p.uid = s.uid
    and s.Status='Y'
)src
pivot
(
  count(stage)
  for stage in (Stage1, Stage2)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7683c/11).

Since you are using SQL Server 2008 this query uses the `VALUES` to generate the list of the genders that you want in the final result set

```
from (values ('F'),('M')) c (gender)
```

Then by using a `LEFT JOIN` on the other tables the final result will return a row for both the `M` and `F` values.

This can also be written using a `UNION ALL` to generate the list of genders:

```
select gender,
  Stage1, 
  Stage2
from
(
  select 
    c.gender,
    'Stage'+cast(stage as varchar(10)) Stage
  from 
  (
    select 'F' gender union all
    select 'M' gender
  ) c
  left join tblpersonaldata p
    on c.gender = p.gender
  left join tblStudentsadmitted s
    on p.uid = s.uid
    and s.Status='Y'
)src
pivot
(
  count(stage)
  for stage in (Stage1, Stage2)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7683c/12)

The result of both is:

```
| GENDER | STAGE1 | STAGE2 |
----------------------------
|      F |      0 |      0 |
|      M |      2 |      1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also working. Using `Left joins` with a new table (*a table with two records for genders `M` & `F`*).

**[Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/673c3/35)**

```
select  t.g Gender,
        isnull(sum(case when Stage = 1 then 1 end),0) Stage1,
        isnull(sum(case when Stage = 2 then 1 end),0) Stage2
from    (values ('M'),('F')) t(g) 
            left join personal a on t.g = a.gender
            left join studentadmitted b on a.uid = b.uid and b.Status = 'Y'
group by t.g
order by t.g

| GENDER | STAGE1 | STAGE2 |
----------------------------
|      F |      0 |      0 |
|      M |      2 |      1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT GENDER, 0 AS 'STAGE 0', 1 AS 'STAGE 1', 2 AS 'STAGE 2'
 FROM 
(
SELECT P.ID, GENDER,CASE WHEN  STAGE IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE STAGE END STAGE
FROM tblPersonaldata  P 
LEFT JOIN tblStudentsadmitted  S ON P.UID = S.UID
) AS A 
PIVOT 
(
COUNT (ID) FOR STAGE IN ([0],[1],[2])
)P